# Laravel - Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm making a system and within this system I have a piece of code which checks for the latest "Order" using the created_at field and it checks the latest "Order_nr" and when a new one is created the number of `order_nr` goes +1. Here is the code I'm talking about

```
$order = new Order;
$order->user_id = Auth()->id();
$latestOrder = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
$order->order_nr = '#'.str_pad($latestOrder->id + 1, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->sub_total = $subtotal;
$order->vat = $vat;
$order->price_sum = $priceSum;
$order->save();
```

this makes every order number unique. When I seed my database the timestamps are all the same. Now when I try to save the order by executing the code above I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '#00000002' for key 'orders_order_nr_unique' (SQL: insert into `orders` (`user_id`, `order_nr`, `sub_total`, `vat`, `price_sum`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, #00000002, 18.12, 3.8052, 21.9252, 2018-03-28 07:30:51, 2018-03-28 07:30:51))

When I change the latest order's time to a second later the code works just fine. How can I solve this? What is the best way to execute this?

Comment: What fields have you made `->unique()` that are going into the `orders` table?

Comment: I made Order_nr unique and that's about it. @Option

Comment: Laravel inserts more than a row each second. So that maybe your select query by created_at descending might not return the very last inserted row. 

Try ordering by ID instead

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `str_pad` with only 8 characters? Are you anticipating that there won't be any order placed after `#99999999`?

Comment: @SaiyanPrince This project won't have 100 million orders. And probably never will. For the time now it works and it can be changed anytime in the future. ;-)

Comment: Why are you using a custom unique index instead of just an increment?

Answer (score 0):

use this

i think you site have many user at a time and more then one user want to do order at single time so i suggeset to use some random number and then bind id

```
$latestOrder = rand() . Order::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use count()

```
$order = new Order;
$order->user_id = Auth()->id();
$totalOrder = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->count();
$order->order_nr = '#'.str_pad($totalOrder + 1, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->sub_total = $subtotal;
$order->vat = $vat;
$order->price_sum = $priceSum;
$order->save();
```

Another option is to order by id DESC:

```
$order = new Order;
$order->user_id = Auth()->id();
$latestOrder = Order::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
$order->order_nr = '#'.str_pad($latestOrder->id + 1, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$order->sub_total = $subtotal;
$order->vat = $vat;
$order->price_sum = $priceSum;
$order->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

SQl query maintains the original order if the value of order by is same, so instead of giving you the last record your query gives you the first row of table.

try auto incremented order_nr or instead of using first with order by desc, find max of order_nr and then do +1